# Checking multiple outputs with one test in Racket

Tags: unit-testing, lisp, racket

I am trying to use the library rackunit to do some tests.

However, I would like to check many outputs with a single test, like this:

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit)

(check-equal? (add1 1) (* 2 1) (- 3 1) (+ 2 0))
```

As you see, this test shall pass, since all outputs are 2.

However, this test fails, due to a syntax problem:

```
 check-equal?: bad syntax in: (check-equal? (add1 1) (* 1 2) (- 3 1) (+ 2 0))
```

Is there a way to do this unique test with multiple procedures returning a value?

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html?q=rackunit) I could not find it.

If I am unable to do this, I think I will be repeating myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just checking numbers, like Gibstick suggested, you can just use `check-true` and `=`. However, if you are not testing numbers, we need to get a little more creative.

If the objects you want to check equality on are transitive: (aka, if `(equal? a b)` and `(equal? b c)` than `(equal? a c)`, you can just run `check-equal?` in a loop:

```
(define items (list 'items 'to 'check))
(define compare-item 'correct-item)
(for ([i (in-list items)])
  (check-equal? i compare-item))
```

Of course, if the item equality is *not* transitive, then you will need to check every item with every other item. You can still do this with a loop, it just becomes a bit more complicated. However, generally speaking, equality testing on items is transitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the more general [`check-true`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html?q=rackunit#%28def._%28%28lib._rackunit%2Fmain..rkt%29._check-true%29%29) with `=`, since all of your values are numbers.

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit)

(check-true (= (add1 1) (* 2 1) (- 3 1) (+ 2 0)))
```

Comment: Creative approach, I haven't thought about that untill now. Thanks. Maybe that's why they do not have a special command for this kind of test.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my original answer. `equal?` does not work -- only `=` does.

Comment: I am actually dealing with outputs which are lists, and not numbers like my example above. Hence, "=" does not work... Do you have another suggestion? @Gibstick

Comment: @Harry the other answer from LeifAndersen deals with the more general case.